# Finding y by the function of x factorization

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried many attempts to get Y by the function of X and I could not.

$\forall x, y \in \!R, y^3 + y = x$

How do you move and find y by the function of x?

Comment: It is possible to solve it but the solution ridiculously unpretty. See: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%5E3%2By-x%3D0%2C+y

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, then you will need to see *Cardano's formula.* It is the counterpart of the quadratic formula for cubic equations like yours. However, it is most times unwieldy. But you could check if you're serious about this.